# The Command tput sgr0 Changes my Terminal Font and Text Colour, how to Stop This? Any echo After tput sgr0 Outputs as Bold White

Tags: macos, echo, tput

When I do `tput sgr0` it changes my terminal font and colour to white (should be black) and looks blocky.

Please see screenshot:

[image]

How do I stop this?

To be more concise, any `echo` after `tput sgr 0` seems to output to bold white, my terminal text colour is black.

#### Update:

My `~.bashrc`:

```bash
export LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1

branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | \ 
  grep \*                 | \ 
  awk '{print$2}'         | \ 
  sed '
    s#^#(#g;
    s#$#)#g
  '
 }

colo() { tput setaf $1; }


PS1='`tput bold``colo 5`\W: `tput sgr0``colo 0``branch``colo 0` \n λ '
```

Comment: Hmm. I notice your question refers to `sgr0` but your example code in the screenshot uses `sgr 0`. Different!

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sgr0` code is described in `man terminfo` as "*turn off all attributes*".

The `sgr` code is described as "*define video attributes #1-#9 (PG9)*" and takes a value `1`..`9`; the sequence `sgr 0` is undefined. You have used both `sgr0` and `sgr 0` in your question.

The remainder of the answer assumes `sgr0`, since the other sequence isn't valid.

---

If using `tput sgr0` resets your terminal to black and white then those colours are part of the default (reset) mode. I assume therefore that rather then configuring your terminal application to use your preferred colour scheme as its default, you have put instructions in one of your shell initialisation files to set specific foreground and background colours. These are (correctly) being reset by the `sgr0` code.

Two possible solutions come to mind,

1. Configure the terminal application directly to use your preferred colours rather then setting them in a shell configuration file, so they become the default reset values
2. Modify the shell prompt command to set your preferred foreground and background attributes each time it's printed

Comment: On many xterm-like terminal emulators, you can also change the default background and foreground colours with escape sequences. Something like `printf '\e]10;black\a\e]11;white\a'`

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot `tput sgr0` and `tput sgr 0` both do the same thing, it's the text that gets turned to white (white bold I think) I'll post my `~/.bashrc` @chrisDavies please see the update. This is the only file where I have colours set.

Comment: maybe it's my mac terminal GUI settings, if it's not the file I added in the update. One more thing the background stays constant, only the text goes bold white after `tput sgr0` please see screenshot, original text is black.

Comment: you are right, I have 7 for white in my `~/.bashrc` thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry that was a `~/.bashrc` for my other machine, please see the updated one.

Comment: It was the terminal settings GUI that had the text as white, thank you, much appreciated.